# How to extract the Response of a RestAssured Call in Java to a class when the fields are wrapped in an object

Tags: java, api, testing, response, rest-assured

I am using Rest Assured (Java) for API Testing an API.
For a specific object, I created a class, lets name it "TestObject", which I pass on to POST Requests to create that object in the api.
Now I want to use the GET Route to extract the object into another TestObject class for checks and further uses.

The problem:
The Fields of my TestObject that I want to save are wrapped in a "content" object in the response JSON.

```
 "Content": {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-07-12T10:02:08.523Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2021-07-12T10:02:08.523Z",
        "UUID": "5ba98999-f6a4-4ec1-8418-ed61022b5975"
 }
```

How can I extract and save the "Content" Object into my TestObject Class?

There is a method in RestAssured that directly extracts the Response to a class, but it then tries to save the Content directly as a variable, which I dont want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use something like this by mapping to response directly to your pojo instead of mapping it to the RestAssured's Response:

Create a POJO named TestObject

```
public class TestObject {

    private ContentObject Content;

    public ContentObject getContent() {
        return Content;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestObject{" +
                "Content=" + Content +
                '}';
    }

    public static class ContentObject {
        private String CreatedAt;
        private String UpdatedAt;
        private String UUID;

        public String getCreatedAt() {
            return CreatedAt;
        }

        public String getUpdatedAt() {
            return UpdatedAt;
        }

        public String getUUID() {
            return UUID;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ContentObject{" +
                    "CreatedAt='" + CreatedAt + '\'' +
                    ", UpdatedAt='" + UpdatedAt + '\'' +
                    ", UUID='" + UUID + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this like:

```
TestObject testObject = when().get("/your/endpoint").then().extract().as(TestObject.class);
System.out.println(testObject);
System.out.println(testObject.getContent());
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggesstion is using Jackson / Gson. Sample code would be:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Map;

public class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    void test1() {
        String res = "{\n" +
                "  \"MetaData\": {\n" +
                "    \n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"Content\": {\n" +
                "    \"CreatedAt\": \"2021-07-13T06:54:32.000Z\",\n" +
                "    \"UpdatedAt\": \"2021-07-13T06:54:32.000Z\",\n" +
                "    \"UUID\": \"2acf44af-209e-4f71-a6e2-2c073dbaf288\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";
        Map<String, Object> json = JsonPath.from(res).get("Content");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectTest objectTest = objectMapper.convertValue(json, ObjectTest.class);
        System.out.println(objectTest);
    }


    static class ObjectTest {
        public String CreatedAt;
        public String UpdatedAt;
        public String UUID;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ObjectTest{" +
                    "CreatedAt='" + CreatedAt + '\'' +
                    ", UpdatedAt='" + UpdatedAt + '\'' +
                    ", UUID='" + UUID + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I'm using Jackson

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is sadly not working.
Sadly, it will not save the fields into the object.

Response response = api.getPartner(v);  
        String res = response.body().asString();
        System.out.println(res);
        Map<String, Object> json = JsonPath.from(res).get("Content");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Partner testpartner = (objectMapper.convertValue(json, Partner.class));
        System.out.println(testpartner.getName().toString());

Comment: `Partner testpartner = (objectMapper.convertValue(json, Partner.class));` Just remove the redundant parentheses () here. Can you tell me what error that you get?

Comment: There is no error returned, it just does not assign it.

Comment: Do you mind if you update exactly json response in question, I will try one more time. 
`Response response = api.getPartner(v); response.prettyPrint();`

Comment: {
    "MetaData": {
        
    },
    "Content": {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-07-13T06:54:32.000Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2021-07-13T06:54:32.000Z",
        "UUID": "2acf44af-209e-4f71-a6e2-2c073dbaf288"
         }
}

Comment: @DarrenLandig There in no problem with my code. It produces the same result as before I just update my anwser to make it clearer. You can also see other answer, it's a good one. Hope this helps.